# Term for 'wounded (Callus-bearing) knuckles'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I have often observed the knuckles of some people bearing weird bruises. 
Googling tells me a 'callus' fits the description of the bruise. Is there a term for these knuckles?

Comment: Anything wrong with using the past participle as in, callused knuckles ?

Comment: Nope. It's fine. But I found the most apt term for it: Russell's sign. (See below).

Comment: Are these bruises or calluses? They are very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the term I was looking for:

### [Russell's Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_sign)

Comment: Really?  You were specifically looking for a term that means bruises on knuckles ***which indicate repeated self induced vomitting??***  Why did you omit this from the original question?

Comment: No. Not really. But I'd noticed this on bulimics...

Comment: If you're not looking for the term specifically for self-induced vomited you'd be unwise to use it as a generalised term for calloused knuckles.

Comment: Indeed. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a more appropriate one, but I'm partial to using the word **gnarled** in this situation. Especially when I want the aged, hard work or ruggedness connotations.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gnarled)

> *adjective*
>
> full of knots or gnarls :  knotty [*gnarled hands*]